# React assinging array vaiable, which one is the best?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, currently, in React, I want to update an array. Which option is the best?

**I have the following:**

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState(['1','2','3']);
```

Now, I want to filter out 3, and only having 1 & 2 in the array.

```
users.filter(item => item.name !== 3)
```

**Which option is the best:**

Option 1, copy array to a new variable:

```
const tempUsers = {... users.filter(item => item.name !== 3)}
setUsers(tempArray);
```

Option 2:

```
setUsers(users.filter(item => item.name !== 3))
```

Which one is better, and why we choose one over another?

Comment: array::filter returns a new array reference, so naturally that is the one I'd choose. Also, your first option would spread the new array into an object, it'd likely still compile and work though, just a very odd way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2,

```
setUsers(users.filter(item => item.name !== 3))
```

Would be sufficient.

This is because `Array.filter()` won't directly mutating state, since it creates a new array. Thus there is no need to take the additional step the spread the result into a new array before setting it to state.

Answer (score 0):

this is a matter of code smell as said by Martin fowler in the book Refactoring.

the second option is better because it is more natural to read and you dont need the extra temp variable [replace temp with query](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceTempWithQuery.html)